# How to sort a list of custom objects by its `previous` and `next` attributes?

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, linked-list

I have a table in which each entity points to the previous and next one in a chain. Dummy ORM model

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Optional


@dataclass
class ChainEl:
    id: str
    prev_el: Optional[str] = None
    next_el: Optional[str] = None
```

I'm not good with algorithms and was wondering if it's possible if it can be done in O(n) or at least better than my solution.

My example code

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import List, Optional


@dataclass
class ChainEl:
    id: str
    prev_el: Optional[str] = None
    next_el: Optional[str] = None


def order_chain(unordered: List[ChainEl]):
    els_with_no_prev = list(filter(lambda x: x.prev_el is None, unordered))
    assert len(els_with_no_prev) == 1

    first_el = els_with_no_prev[0]
    ordered = [first_el]

    last_found = first_el
    unordered.remove(first_el)

    while unordered:
        for this_el in unordered:
            if this_el.id == last_found.next_el:
                ordered.append(this_el)
                last_found = this_el
                unordered.remove(this_el)
                break
        else:
            raise RuntimeError("Run out of items")

    assert ordered[-1].next_el is None

    return ordered


import random

proper_order = ['c', 'b', 'd']

first_el = ChainEl(id='c', prev_el=None, next_el='b')
second_el = ChainEl(id='b', prev_el='c', next_el='d')
third_el = ChainEl(id='d', prev_el='b', next_el=None)
unordered = [first_el, second_el, third_el]
random.shuffle(unordered)

ordered_chain = order_chain(unordered)
print(ordered_chain)
```

Comment: @TomWojcik Should any weight be given to the element `id`'s? If yes, that can be used to sort. If not, effectively you want to sort a chain of elements, based on the element's order in the chain? Can we assume that (a) the chain is definitely not cyclic and (b) the elements are continuous? ie no missing elements in the chain?

Comment: `id`s are unordered uuids. The user can reorder some components from the UI however they want and these components are corresponding links in this chain. Each `id` is unique, they are not cyclic. There will be no missing elements. Only two null values in all links in chain, first.previous and last.next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach I've used is:

1. Create a dictionary `elems` with all the element `id`s as keys. The values are the elements. (Note that it's a *reference* to the existing element, and not a copy, so it doesn't double the memory usage.)
2. While creating that dictionary, when the element whose `prev_el` is `None` is found, make that the first element of `ordered`.
3. Then iterate over `ordered` (which first has just the *first* element) and use each `next_el` to get that element from the `elems` dictionary. Do that until that last element is ordered has the `next_el` `None`.

```py
def order_chain(unordered: List[ChainEl]):
    if len(unordered) < 2:
        # 0 or 1 element, it's sorted, return
        return unordered
    # dict of all the elements
    elems = {}
    for el in unordered:
        if el.prev_el is None:
            ordered = [el]  # initialises the ordered list
        elems[el.id] = el

    while ordered[-1].next_el is not None:
        # `[ordered[-1]` is always the last element
        ordered.append(elems[ordered[-1].next_el])
    return ordered

# output of `order_chain(unordered)`
[ChainEl(id='c', prev_el=None, next_el='b'),
 ChainEl(id='b', prev_el='c', next_el='d'),
 ChainEl(id='d', prev_el='b', next_el=None)
]
```

This iterates over the elements twice: Once to create elems and once to populate `ordered`. Dictionary lookups are O(1).

Some improvements:

- Disregard these comments; I didn't account for *"I have a table in which each entity..."* - so the source is text data

  - Consider storing a reference (actually, a [WeakReference object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/weakref.html#weak-reference-objects)) to the previous and next elements, rather than the text of the `id`'s.
  - Then you can navigate the chain from any point and don't actually need it to be sorted.
  - Optionally, have a reference to the `first` and `last` elements in separate variables outside the dataclass so you have that info ready.
- If you are working a lot with the references/chains, do the initial `elems` dict and then, instead of creating a sorted list, use WeakReferences and replace the existing `prev_el` and `next_el` strings with weakrefs to the actual object.

  - That way you'd have an actual [*Linked List*](https://www.google.com/search?q=python+linked+lists), which may be more useful.
- *Another edit:* When you initially create the chain of elements from the table, you could directly create it as a dictionary, instead of a list.

  ```py
  elems = {}
  for row in sql_results:
       elems[row['id']] = ChainEl(id=row['id'], prev_el=row['prev'], next_el=row['next'])
       if row['prev'] is None:
           first = row['id']
       if row['next'] is None:
           last = row['id']
  ```

  - For ordering, you'd only need to create a list of element `id`s, which you can lookup in the `elems` dict created when reading the sql data. The creation of the list would be similar to my code above, modified to store only the `id` text. Or put that into an [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict).

Comment: Ha, I knew there's a nice solution that I just can't come up with. Thanks!

Comment: You started with the right idea - to find the first elem (where `prev_el is None`) and initialise your `ordered` list with that. For your inner loop, instead of tracking `last_found`, you could use `ordered[-1]` which is the last found, and in order. That would make it nearly the same as my solution. The major change is your 2nd loop which keeps iterating over `unordered` until it's empty. That effectively made your method O(N²). Btw, since lists are mutable objects, your function changes the input list - which is usually not expected when a func returns a new list.

Comment: @TomWojcik FYI, see my edit for how you could initialise the chain more effectively, when you're reading the unordered SQL data.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the effort. I know mutating the list while iterating over it might result with errors, hence in a while loop I always start over. And yes, I knew it's O(n^2) and I knew there has to be a better solution. Now I know what it is :)

Comment: I read a long time ago about linked lists. Will refresh my memory.

Comment: That's not what I meant - indeed you're breaking out of the loop when you find an element and modify `unordered` (which is good). I meant - imagine another user passed in an unordered list to your function `order_chain` and they got an ordered list back. But if you do `print(unordered)` is after calling `order_chain(unordered)`, you'll see that `unordered` is now empty.